# Transpose Pandas dataframe preserving the index

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I have a problem while transposing a Pandas DataFrame that has the following structure:

```
            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
foo         0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  14   1   0   1   0   0   0
bar         0  6  0  0  4  0  5  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
lorem       1  3  0  0  0  1  0  0  2  0   3   0   1   2   1   1   0
ipsum       1  2  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0   0   0   4   0   6   0   0
dolor       1  2  4  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   2   0   0   1   0   0   2
..
```

With index:

```
foo,bar,lorem,ipsum,dolor,...
```

And this is basically a terms-documents matrix, where rows are terms and the headers (0-16) are document indexes.
Since my purpose is clustering documents and not terms, I want to transpose the dataframe and use this to perform a cosine-distance computation between documents themselves.
But when I transpose with:

```
pd.transpose()
```

I get:

```
   foo       bar    ...       pippo                     lorem
0    0         0    ...       0                         0
1    4         6    ...       0                         0
2    0         0    ...       0                         0
3    0         0    ...       0                         0
4    0         4    ...       0                         0
..
16   0         2    ...       0                         1
```

With index:

```
0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , ... , 15, 16
```

**What I would like?**
I'm looking for a way to make this operation preserving the dataframe index. Basically the first row of my new df should be the index.

Thank you

Comment: The matrix is of the same shape right? (for example 8x8) ?

Comment: No, the base (First) Matrix is , in general, N x M with N >> M.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a series of unstack

```
df2 = df.unstack().to_frame().unstack(1).droplevel(0,axis=1)
```

---

```
print(df2)


   foo bar lorem ipsum dolor
0    0   0     1     1     1
1    4   6     3     2     2
2    0   0     0     0     4
3    0   0     0     1     0
4    0   4     0     0     1
5    0   0     1     0     0
6    0   5     0     1     0
7    0   0     0     0     0
8    0   0     2     0     0
9    0   0     0     0     0
10  14   0     3     0     2
11   1   0     0     0     0
12   0   0     1     4     0
13   1   0     2     0     1
14   0   1     1     6     0
15   0   0     1     0     0
16   0   0     0     0     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data is square matrix (n x n) and if I understand the question correctly

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 4,0], [0,6,0], [1,3,0]], 
                   index =['foo', 'bar', 'lorem'], 
                   columns=[0, 1, 2]
                   )
 df_T = pd.DataFrame(df.values.T, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```